# Halogy CMS - custom navigation

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system, codeigniter-2, halogy

Hy, i just recently started to use Halogy, it's a cms based on codeigniter.
I'm currently just checking it out so i'm using the free version, but i cant get my mind wrapped around the custom navigation option.

First of all i cant access the navigation section, and i cant show custom navigation in the template using this {navigation(custom)}

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Well! I am glad someone is using it. For your problem go to pages creat a page save and publish it and it will be available to use. That's all.